# JavaScript dynamic object keys ejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ejs

I really cannot find a way to describe this. Essentially I have a database that can have any number of tables with different column lengths and names. I have a table which defines each table and it's columns. I have a query to search for values within these tables, and I pass the results of the search and the columns to ejs using express. What I need is to echo the results. I do have:

```
<div class="row">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <% columns.forEach(function(column) { %>
                <th><%= column %></th>
            <% }); %>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    ...
```

This outputs the name of the columns in the table header correctly. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to print the actual results however. I have tried many different ways but all I keep getting is undefined or [Object object]. I have this currently:

```
<tbody>
        <% for(var r = 0; r < results.length; r++) { %>
            <tr>
                ... need to access column here ...
            </tr>
        <% } %>
    </tbody>
```

I first tried the following (inside above)

```
<% for(var key in Object.keys(results[r])) { %>
    <%= results[r].key %>
<% } %>
```

followed by so many different attempts along the lines of this. I suppose the issue is not knowing the possible key names. I don't even know what to search for either to be entirely honest. My mind is drawing a blank.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys` returns an array of all the keys in an object. You can use `forEach` to iterate over those keys, to access the value of the object via `object[key]`

Also, you can use `forEach` on your results instead of `for` to keep things clean.

```
<% results.forEach(function (result) { %>
  <tr>
  <%  Object.keys(result).forEach(function (key) { %>
    <td><%= result[key] %> </td>
  <% }) %>
  </tr>
<% }) %>
```

Modern browsers have arrows now, so this can be simplified a little:

```
<% results.forEach(result => { %>
  <tr>
  <%  Object.keys(result).forEach(key => { %>
    <td><%= result[key] %> </td>
  <% }) %>
  </tr>
<% }) %>
```